# Select multiple entries with ui-select-match

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ui-select

I had this in my template:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="selectedProjectTypes" theme="select2" style="min-width: 200px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Typ...">
        [[selectedProjectTypes]]
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="project_type in project_types">
        <div>[[project_type.name]]</div>
    </ui-select-choices>
```

my `[[selectedProjectTypes]]` contains the selected values.
When I open the form there is nothing in there. 
(an api returns the related entries. - this works)

`project_types` contains this:

```
[{"id":4,"slug":"event","active":1,"name":"Event","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","updated_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","deleted_at":null},{"id":5,"slug":"sfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsf","active":1,"name":"sfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsf","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 09:50:23","updated_at":"2015-12-22 09:50:23","deleted_at":null},{"id":6,"slug":"eteett","active":1,"name":"eteett","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 10:07:55","updated_at":"2015-12-22 10:07:55","deleted_at":null},{"id":7,"slug":"sfssfsf","active":1,"name":"sfssfsf","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 12:36:37","updated_at":"2015-12-22 12:36:37","deleted_at":null}]
```

this is an array of json objects. This was filled by an api.
With this:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="project_type in project_types">
    <div>[[project_type.name]]</div>
</ui-select-choices>
```

I can loop through the array and the select field shows all the options with the project_type name. It works.

But when I try to select the options of my select the whole json element of the first array element will be selecting...(no matter what option I choose).

How can I fix it that only the corresponding name will show in the select field if I select an option?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the whole object in ui-select-choices directive. Please try the below code :

```
$scope.project_type = {}; 

 <p>Selected: {{project_type.selected}}</p>
 <ui-select ng-model="project_type.selected" theme="select2" style="min-width: 300px;">
   <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="project_type.name as project_type  in project_types ">
    <div ng-bind-html="project_type.name"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

Comment: no sry if I try this, I have the whole json object between <option></option>

Comment: I did not get you. I've edited my answer please try that code and let me know if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: It should work for multiple select too. Add 'multiple' attribute to the ui-select directive.

Comment: I got it worked with this the $item variable:
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select Typ...">
       [[$item.name]]
</ui-select-match>

Comment: Okay. This example from demos might help  for multiselct :      https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo-multi-select.html